How to solve this 2D Laplace equation $-\Delta u=0 $ with $u(x,y)=y^{2}$ on boundary
$$
\mbox{I want to solve}\quad\Delta u = 0\quad\mbox{with}\quad u(x,y) = y^{2}
$$
on boundary: The region is a $2D$ ball centered at $0$ with radius $1$.
I want to write it in polar coordinates but it can't be separated: I guess the solution is of the form
$$
f\left(r\right)\sin^{2}(\theta)\quad\mbox{since the boundary condition reads}\quad
y^{2} = r^{2}\sin^{2}\left(\theta\right)
$$

What's the boundary condition then? $u(r=1,\theta)=r^2\sin^2\theta$ or $u(r=1,\theta)=\sin^2\theta$?

$u(x,y)=y^2$ on the boundary @Conreu

And in polar coordinates?

this is in cartesian coord, in polar form, it should be $u(r,\theta)=r^2sin^2(\theta)$

while r=1, it should be $(1,)=^2()$

I want to use the poisson formula to solve it https://www.math.arizona.edu/~kglasner/math456/SEPARATION_VARIABLES2.pdf

What's the issue then? You just need to compute
$$u(r,\theta)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\dfrac{(1-r^2)\sin^2\alpha}{1-2\cos(\theta-\alpha)+r^2},\mathrm d\alpha$$

how to compute this integral@Conreu

In order to solve Laplace's equation with the given boundary condition, we make the following observations:

$y^2=\sin^2\theta$ on the boundary of the region;

$\sin^2\theta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos 2\theta)$;

$u=1$ and $u=r^2\cos 2\theta$ satisfy $\Delta u=0$;

Laplace's equation is linear.


Therefore, the solution that satisfies the boundary condition is
$$
u(r,\theta)=\frac{1}{2}(1-r^2\cos 2\theta).
$$

I’m guessing OP is looking for somewhat more constructive insight, but I could be wrong.

According to theory (see Theorem 5.1 in Harmonic Function Theory by Axler, Bourdon & Ramey), for the Dirichlet problem on the unit ball with boundary values given by a polynomial $p$ which is homogeneous of degree $m$, the solution has the form
$$
u(\mathbf{x}) = p(\mathbf{x}) + (1-|\mathbf{x}|^2) \, q(\mathbf{x})
$$
for a uniquely determined polynomial $q$ of degree at most $m-2$.
In your case, $p(x,y)=y^2$ is quadratic, so $q(x,y)$ must have degree zero; in other words, $q(x,y)=c$ for some constant $c$. So all you have to do is determine the unique constant $c$ which makes
$$
u(x,y) = y^2 + (1-x^2-y^2) \, c
$$
harmonic, and then you have the solution.

The solution to this Dirichlet problem is
$$
u(x,y) = \frac{1 - x^2 + y^2}{2}.
$$
The function above is clearly harmonic on $\mathbf{R}^2$. To check its boundary values, replace $x^2$ with $1 - y^2$ in the expression above to show that $u(x,y) = y^2$ for $(x, y)$ on the unit circle.
The solution to this Dirichlet problem was found by using the free Mathematica package that is available at https://www.axler.net/HFT_Math.html.

The general solution according to separation of variables is
$$u(r,\theta)=\dfrac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}r^n[a_n\cos(n\theta)+b_n\sin(n\theta)]$$
If at the boundary $u(a,\theta)=a^2\sin^2\theta$ is satisfied, then, in order to find the coefficients of the series we need to develop a Fourier Series of that function for $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$:
$$a^2\sin^2\theta=\dfrac{a^2}{2}-\dfrac{a^2}{2}\cos(2\theta)=\dfrac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}a^n[a_n\cos(n\theta)+b_n\sin(n\theta)],$$
and thus, by comparison, $a_0=a^2,\ a_2=-\frac{1}{2}$ and the rest of coefficients are zero.
To sum up we're left with
$$\begin{aligned}
u(r,\theta)&=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\left[1-\dfrac{r^2}{a^2}\cos(2\theta)\right]\\
&=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\left[1-\dfrac{r^2}{a^2}(\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)\right]\\
&=\dfrac{a^2}{2}\left[1-\dfrac{x^2-y^2}{a^2}\right]\\
&\overset{a=1}{=}\color{blue}{\dfrac{1}{2}\left[1-x^2+y^2\right]=u(x,y)}
\end{aligned}$$
